# Get Data from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tyring to build and minify my JS using grunt, When i build i didn't get any errors but while minifying i'm  getting an error like

```js
   ../source/js/browse-container.js
   1013 |                   var cards = listCards;
                                        ^ 'listCards' is not defined.

>> 1 error in 1 file
Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Below is the code,I don't see any errors in console, i just get that above error while trying to minify. (Minification is done using uglify)

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong ?

```js
    fetchListStatic: function(){

       var cards = listCards;

     return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      if (typeof (cards) !== 'undefined') {
       
       //var cards = listCards;

       resolve(cards);

      } else {
       resolve([]);
      }
     });
                },
```

Comment: try defining listCards first before assigning it to cards

Comment: the error is not due to minification  but due to jshint task.

Comment: Where is 'listCards' defined ?

Comment: I've declared it inside this function ` initFeed: function () { var listCards } line 376`

Answer (score 0):

I've declared the listCards globally. Hence resolved my issue

```js
 var moment, hbs, promise, listCards;

  function BrowseContainer() {
  }
```